# Что означает термин аллокация (новый объект, память)?

Tags: java, терминология

Что означает термин аллокация?

Встречаю его периодически, но только в контексте:

1. Эффективная аллокация памяти
2. Создание аллокатора при создании объекта
3. Синхронизация аллоцирующих потоков и т.п.

А что это такое не видел четкого определения.

Comment: Я набрал в Google запрос "java аллокация" и получил целую кучу русскоязычных статей, из которых легко понять значение этого термина.

Comment: Сразу видно, что не кодил в сях, там то уж сразу видишь функцию `alloc()` и сразу понимаешь о чем идет речь :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Означает выделение блока памяти, чаще всего в куче.

Answer (score 2):

Калька с английского allocation -  распределение.
Смысл дословный. Управлять памятью, распределять ее и т.п.